# Yodlee - getAllSiteAccounts API call returning invalid json formate like "[{..]}"

Tags: java, json, yodlee

I tried yodlee - [getAllSiteAccounts](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getAllSiteAccounts) call and getting json response with added Square Bracket "[" in front and end of the json response. It looks invalid json format. I tried some other API calls like cobrand and login but these calls are returning json response correctly without Square Bracket added.

Can I fix this by yodlee anyway?

OR

Do I need to hack in java?

Json response:

> [{"siteAccountId":10092746,"isCustom":false,"credentialsChangedTime":1445919903,"siteRefreshInfo":{"siteRefreshStatus":{"siteRefreshStatusId":5,"siteRefreshStatus":"REFRESH_COMPLETED"},"siteRefreshMode":{"refreshModeId":2,"refreshMode":"NORMAL"},"updateInitTime":0,"nextUpdate":1446455585,"code":0,"itemRefreshInfo":[{"memItemId":10147022,"itemSuggestedFlow":{"suggestedFlowId":2,"suggestedFlow":"REFRESH"},"errorCode":0,"retryCount":0}],"noOfRetry":0,"isMFAInputRequired":false,"siteAddStatus":{"siteAddStatusId":14,"siteAddStatus":"ADDED"}},"siteInfo":{"popularity":0,"siteId":16441,"orgId":1148,"defaultDisplayName":"Dag
>   Site","defaultOrgDisplayName":"Demo
>   Bank","contentServiceInfos":[{"contentServiceId":20559,"siteId":16441,"containerInfo":{"containerName":"bank","assetType":1}},{"contentServiceId":20560,"siteId":16441,"containerInfo":{"containerName":"bills","assetType":0}},{"contentServiceId":20561,"siteId":16441,"containerInfo":{"containerName":"credits","assetType":2}},{"contentServiceId":20562,"siteId":16441,"containerInfo":{"containerName":"insurance","assetType":2}},{"contentServiceId":20549,"siteId":16441,"containerInfo":{"containerName":"stocks","assetType":1}},{"contentServiceId":20563,"siteId":16441,"containerInfo":{"containerName":"loans","assetType":2}},{"contentServiceId":20564,"siteId":16441,"containerInfo":{"containerName":"miles","assetType":0}}],"enabledContainers":[{"containerName":"bank","assetType":1},{"containerName":"bills","assetType":0},{"containerName":"credits","assetType":2},{"containerName":"insurance","assetType":2},{"containerName":"stocks","assetType":1},{"containerName":"loans","assetType":2},{"containerName":"miles","assetType":0}],"baseUrl":"http://64.14.28.129/dag/index.do","loginForms":[],"isHeld":false,"isCustom":false,"siteSearchVisibility":true,"loginUrl":"http://64.14.28.129/dag/index.do","isAlreadyAddedByUser":true,"isOauthEnabled":false,"hdLogoLastModified":0,"isHdLogoAvailable":false},"created":"2015-10-26T21:25:03-0700","retryCount":0,"disabled":false,"isAgentError":false,"isSiteError":false,"isUARError":false}]

Thanks.

Comment: Malformed JSON from a web service should not be your responsibility as the consumer of that service.  It should be up to the web service to fix this problem.

Comment: `"siteRefreshStatus":"siteRefreshStatusId":5` ... this looks seriously wrong

Comment: Thanks Tim, I realized why I am getting this response with Square Bracket added. This response should have list items so they are sending as arrays with added Square Bracket.

Comment: I think the JSON has other problems too.

Comment: Yes Tim, the json response format looks like as below. each one is a Item so that should be covered with square bracket right?

[  
  {  },
  {  },
  {  },
  {  },
  {  },
  {  },
  {  }
]

Comment: This looks right, but as I pointed out, there are other formatting problems.

Comment: Hi Ganesa , you are right and I also validated the JSON response you posted using this website https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ .  and according to this it's a valid JSON response.

Comment: Yes Shreyans, I validated as you did but some time I am getting JSON object and some time getting JSON array Object so working on handling this in my side. Thanks

Comment: Shreyans, I am facing new problem on  getAllSiteAccounts API. I am getting two kind of results for same request as below
1. [{}{}{}] - If I have account I am getting json array with all account details correctly.
2. {{}} - If I am not linked any account or there is no accounts are available that time I am getting plain json response